Sprouted pumpkin seeds
My 10 year old son saved his pumpkin seeds from this years Halloween as he seen a recipe he wanted me to do with them, he put them in a tub with wet paper towels and left them. we never got round to doing the recipe and they have now sprouted, I haven't the slightest clue when it comes to gardening so please can you help us turn these into pumpkins for next years Halloween. All I know is I cannot plant them outside until April/may. If I keep them in the tub will they die?

Hi Chantelle, welcome to the site!  Where in the world do you live?  Do you have any seeds that didn't sprout, so you can let them sprout next spring when the world is ready for them?

Also, how much light does the tub get, and how cold does it get?
